# At least one mapping is required erro in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2

Here's a problem: I would like to protect a URI until authorized with some third-party OAuth2. Based on http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableOAuth2Client.html, I have these:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class OAuth2Client extends OAuth2ClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Filter filter() {
        DelegatingFilterProxy f = new DelegatingFilterProxy();
        f.setTargetBeanName("oauth2ClientContextFilter");
        return f;
    }

    @Resource
    @Qualifier("oauth2ClientContextFilter")
    private OAuth2ClientContextFilter oauth2ClientContextFilter;

    @Resource
    @Qualifier("accessTokenRequest")
    private AccessTokenRequest accessTokenRequest;

    @Bean
    public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails remote() {
        AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails details = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
        details.setUserAuthorizationUri("http://localhost2/oauth/authorize");
        return details;
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate() {
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(remote(), new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(
                accessTokenRequest));
    }

}
```

And

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    // Empty for now...
}
```

And finally

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        super.configure(auth);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/protectedUri").and()
                .authorizeRequests().requestMatchers()
                .hasRole("#oauth2.hasScope('read')");

    }
}
```

But this gives:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: At least one mapping is required
>   (i.e. authorizeRequests().anyRequest.authenticated())

I've tried quite a few combinations of the HttpSecurity builder to no avail - any help, or is this approach entirely off base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this approach entirely off base?

Yes. An empty `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` isn't going to help you. You should configure the protected paths, e.g.

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/protectedUri").authenticated();
}
```

(and leave out your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`).

The client configuration at the top looks wrong too, but it's not relevant to the protected resource (start a new question if you want to know how to configure the client).

Comment: Yes the client config I left for later. But now that I get rid of WebSEcurityConfigurerAdapter and added the configure call into ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter I get

Error creating bean with name 'oauth2ClientContextFilter': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

Comment: If you left it for later why is it still there?

Comment: I left the figuring out of it for later - does it matter?

Comment: A resource server doesn't need an `OAuth2ClientContextFilter`, so I guess you still have a remnant of the client config to remove?

Comment: Wait - I'm trying to go by http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableOAuth2Client.html -- I have a resource protected and wish to use a third-party to authorize it.

Comment: It doesn't say anything there about protecting resources. It's about the client (the code snippet is out of date, but that's not relevant here).

Comment: Right - protecting the resource is done with ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter but who can then be responsible for asking the third party to authorize the access to the resource? Would it not be the oauth client?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "asking". Is it really a token-protected resource? If so the ball you need is `@EnableResourceServer`.

Comment: Right, it is a token protected resource; and the @EnableResourceServer, as shown above, results in an error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26007110/at-least-one-mapping-is-required-erro-in-spring#comment40761612_26013190. 

So the resource server would be responsible for protecting the resource and using OAuth2ClientContextFilter to determine whether to allow access or to have OAuth2ClientContextFilter get the token -- and I am sure I'm missing something. I get how the OAuth2 flow for the token auth works, I can do it by hand, but am having a hard time matching the right Spring flow to it.

Comment: You are missing something. `@EnableResourceServer` installs a filter of type `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter`. You don't need any client config.

Comment: Would you mind then telling me what I'm missing? I am not sure where to even look for help.

Comment: There are loads of samples to look at (server side code with no client configuration), but really all you need is `@EnableOAuth2Resource` (plus a `TokenStore` if the auth server is remote). If they can't show you the way to do it, maybe you need to start again and state your goals more clearly?

Comment: Maybe - I just wasn't able to find any - could you point me to one so I can eat my hat?

Comment: Didn't think what? You don't want to re-state your goals? Or you don't want to look at samples and try and learn something?

Comment: "Maybe - I just wasn't able to find any - could you point me to one so I can eat my hat? "

Comment: Lots of Spring Boot samples here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/tests/annotation, and one without https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples